# React-Admin: How to open "Drawer" on the same page/route as the "List"?

Tags: react-router, react-admin

I'm trying to reproduce the [React-Admin DEMO](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/reviews/25) with functionality on [how the review list](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/2.x/examples/demo/src/reviews/ReviewList.js) functions.

In there, is a `List` of items and once a row is clicked, the `Show` view appears on the right. Notice below that my code snippet is very similar to the demo example, but the `Drawer` doesn't open and instead the `Show` view opens on a new page.

**Please note a key difference:**
My `List` and `Datagrid` fetch data via different `resources`, and am able to combine the two using a `ReferenceManyField`.

The `List` render employees, and the `Show` should render a list of the employee's timesheet.

```js
// I think my problem is that, this always returns "false"
const isMatch = !!(
  match &&
  match.params &&
  match.params.id !== 'create'
);
```

Here's my code, and thanks for any help:

```
class NestedTimesheetList extends React.Component {
  handleClose = () => {
    this.props.push('/timesheets');
  };

  render() {
    const { push, classes, ...props } = this.props; 

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Route path="/timesheets/show/:id">
          {({ match }) => {
           const isMatch = !!(match && match.params && match.params.id !== 'create');
           let details = (id, basePath, record) => (
              // triggered by rowClick
              linkToRecord('/TimesheetSummary', record.id, 'show') + 
              `?employeeId=${props.id}&employeeCode=${props.record.employeeCode}`
           );

           return (
             <Fragment>
               <List
                {...props}
                className={classnames(classes.list, {[classes.listWithDrawer]: isMatch})}
                sort={{ field: "name", order: "ASC" }}
               >                
                 <ReferenceManyField 
                   {...props}
                   sort={{ field: "startTime", order: "DESC" }} 
                   reference="TimesheetSummary" 
                   source="employeeCode" 
                   target="employeeCode" 
                   label={false}
                 >                                      
                   <Datagrid rowClick={details} {...props}>
                     <TextField  
                       label="Timesheet ID"
                       source="timesheetID" 
                       sortable={false} 
                     />
                     <FunctionField 
                       label="Start Time" 
                       source="startTime"
                       render={record => `${dateFormat(record.startTime)}`} 
                       sortable={false} 
                      />                                                
                    </Datagrid>
                 </ReferenceManyField>
               </List>
               <Drawer 
                 variant="persistent" 
                 open={isMatch} 
                 anchor="right" 
                 onClose={this.handleClose}
                 classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
               >
                 {/* To avoid any errors if the route does not match, 
                   we don't render at all the component in this case */}
                 { isMatch ? (
                    <TimesheetsummaryShow
                      {...props}
                      id={match.params.id}
                      onCancel={this.handleClose}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </Drawer>
              </Fragment>
            );
         }}
       </Route>
     </div>
   );
}
```

The Admin resource definition for this:

```
import TimesheetSummary from './timesheets/index';
<Resource name="TimesheetSummary"  {...TimesheetSummary} />
```

Here is the timesheet index:

```
import TimesheetsummaryShow  from './timesheetShow';
import  TimesheetCreate  from './TimesheetCreate';

export default {
    create: TimesheetCreate,
    show: TimesheetsummaryShow
};
```

Comment: A couple of things to identify, the standard is that a `List` is rendered at `/path/` not `/path/:id`. So try placing the `<List>` outside that `<Route>` and leave the `<Drawer>` within. What happens?

Comment: I tried that and didn't have any luck. It doesn't appear to be even recognizing that route or drawer exists. Clicking on the row immediately just opens a new page. I'm wondering if there's something in the index or App that is the problem.

Comment: That's interesting. Indeed, showing us how the `resources` are declared within the `<Admin>` might help too...

Comment: Here is the index for timesheets and then the <Admin> code: 
 
`import TimesheetsummaryShow  from './timesheetShow';
import  TimesheetCreate  from './TimesheetCreate';

export { TimesheetsummaryShow };
export { TimesheetCreate };`

<Admin>
`import{ TimesheetsummaryShow, TimesheetCreate } from './timesheets';

      <Resource name="TimesheetSummary" 
                show={TimesheetsummaryShow} 
                create={TimesheetCreate} />`

Comment: Kindly update that to the question, many readers might miss it. Thanks.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the concept that I'm working with 2 different resources? I tried the same thing with 1 resource and it works.

Comment: It's interesting, did you just forget to include the "list" part within the `/timesheet/index.js`?

Comment: I did try adding the "list", but I'm starting to believe that it's an issue with 2 different resources. My next attempt is to simply call the timesheet list page from within the employee show page like this: <TimesheetList {...props} />
However, when I do that, it DOES bring up the timesheet list page, but it still thinks it's using the Employee resource. Is there a way to change which resource is being used when I call the Timesheet list?